# Trouble installing Karma 1.6 with Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I was using karma 1.2 and angular 2. I'm successfully upgraded system to Angular 4. But now I'm trying to update Karma to version 1.6 but have following errors:

[image]

Why I see here "Unmet peer dependency" issue?

Comment: You find the cause of the "Unmet peer dependency" at the bottom of the npm log. Something like: "npm WARN module requires a peer of otherModule but none was installed"

Comment: so some modules require @angular/common@4.0.2 etc.. but @angular/common@4.0.2 wasnt found?

Comment: You have probably 4.0.2 installed, but some other module requires an older or newer one. Can you add more of the log?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Karma because it doesn't depend on Angular in any way. 'Unmet peer dependency' should be shown on *any* installation, not just Karma. This is NPM question, not Karma or TypeScript. Provide your package.json.

Answer (score -1):

follow this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli..

Your app should work just fine. I recently upgraded to angular 4.0 and didn't face any issue at all.

it will update angular-CLI, angular and karma will be installed to the latest version automatically